# Which contoller action should be use for ajax calls in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I am making a search box. The thing I am missing is there are two controllers, ActionController and the RestfulController. I do an ajax call, which is done via jQuery. Now, it works okay with ActionController and shows the results. Question is when to use RestufulController. Does it when we really need a GET, POST, PUT and DELETE via restful services? IMO, I can use it as a GET scenario for getting results of typed 'search' text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AbstractRestfulController` should be used when you work with a RESTful interface. There is no need to use the rest controller for non-rest applications. To learn what is REST, check the various resources you can find online. In short, REST is about managing entities with HTTP verbs. So you can have a "book", where you retrieve a list of all books, get the properties of a specific book, create a new one, update an existing one and delete a book. Your search is not about this type of entities. It's just a query you expect a result from.

In your case, the search is no REST specific. You can use the "normal" `AbstractActionController` and connect a route to a `searchAction` for instance. If you have a complete RESTful interface, it is "ok" to apply REST to search and allow a GET request to `/search`. But if you're not fully REST, don't start with search to implement it :)

Comment: yea thats similar to my thoughts.